# Not able to get the logic of below code

Tags: java, interface

```
public interface AI {
    public static final int A = BI.B+1;
}
public interface BI {
    public static final int B = CI.C;
}
public interface CI extends AI {
    public static final int C = A+1;
}

public class Test implements AI, CI, BI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("A : " + A);
        System.out.println("B : " + B);
        System.out.println("C : " + C);
        System.out.println(A+B+C);
    }

}
```

O/p --> 4

Can someone please help me out in understanding the code flow and logic behind the output 4?
Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  The OP hasn't demonstrated any understanding at all, but I think it's a legitimate question because of the interaction of the interfaces being loaded.

Comment: @rgettman agreed. this is a good question if worded differently. I was trying this out on C# (no java installed on this pc and online compilers don't support more than 1 file) and it was bugging me how I couldn't set things up. Also, I've seen this kind of questions in a college java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of the variables in the interfaces aren't set until the interfaces are loaded.  They are loaded by the first statement:

```
System.out.println("A : " + A);
```

This causes `AI` to be loaded and initialized.  It attempts to set the value of `A` to `BI.B+1`.

This causes `BI` to be loaded and initialized.  It attempts to set the value of `B` to `C1.C`.

This causes `CI` to be loaded and initialized.  Here, the fact that it extends `AI` only allows `A` to be referenced by a simple name.  It's set to `A+1`.  Techncially, `AI` is still being initialized; the `A` value in `AI` isn't set yet.  In Java, a variable that isn't set has a default value, which for primitive numeric types is `0`.

So, 'C' gets the value `1`, and `B` also gets `1`.  That means that `A` is set to `2`.  That's why the output from the first 3 print statements is

```
A : 2
B : 1
C : 1
```

And of course those values add to `4`.

Additionally, I hope that this is just a puzzle and not real code; it appears that this trick allows one to read a `static final` variable before it's even set (`AI.A` as `0` in the `CI` initialization of `C`).  The [JLS, Section 9.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3.1), states:

> Note that interface fields that are constant variables (§4.12.4) are initialized before other interface fields. This also applies to static fields that are constant variables in classes (§8.3.2). Such fields will never be observed to have their default initial values (§4.12.5), even by devious programs.

None of the values that are initializing your `static final` variables are constant expressions, so they aren't constant variables.  Constant variables are `final` variables initialized with a constant expression.  That makes this a  "devious program".

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out and giving such a wonderful explanation .

Comment: You're welcome.  On each question, you have a choice of [accepting exactly one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that you think helps you the most.